# How do I use the geoip_language_redirect module?

Tags: users, i18n-l10n, redirection, multi-sites

I am working on a multilingual website, and I have setup the multilingual concept successfully.
Now I want to redirect the users to the corresponding language URL based on the IP address or country. For example, if users are from france, I want to redirect them to http://www.example.com/fr like.

I found the geoip_language_redirect module, but I don't know how to use it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

As the [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip_language_redirect) says, after you installed the module, you need to set up the *geoip_redirect_mapping* persistent variable with an array that associate the ISO country code with the language.

```
variable_set('geoip_redirect_mapping', array(
  'GB' => 'en',
  'FR' => 'fr',
  // …
));
```

For example, put the following code in setup.php, and save it in the same directory where Drupal has its cron.php and index.php.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
variable_set('geoip_redirect_mapping', array(
  'GB' => 'en',
  'FR' => 'fr',
  // …
));
```

Visit http://example.com/setup.php, and the variable will be setup. After this, you can delete the file.

If you have Drush, then you can alternatively execute the following command from the site directory (from the terminal).

```
php -r "print json_encode(array('GB' => 'en', 'FR' => 'fr'));"  | drush vset --format=json geoip_redirect_mapping -
```

For the rest, the module automatically redirects the users.

#### Please note the following

The project page is a little confusing. It's not clear if the persistent variable is *geoip_mapping* or *geoip_redirect_mapping*. I didn't find in the code any reference to that variable, so I cannot confirm which one is correct. I would try *geoip_redirect_mapping*, since that is the one used from the example code; if that doesn't work, I would try *geoip_mapping*. If neither of them works, I would open a support request for the module, if there isn't one already, asking to change the project page to make it clearer.